# "make it to there"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, phrases

Consider the following two phrases which are both about going to some place:

> If I can't make it there
>
> If I can't make it *to* there

Isn't the second phrase grammatically correct, whereas the first is not? If they are both correct and both mean the same thing, then what's the difference, if anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No your first example is grammatically correct and your second is incorrect†.

In English *there* can be used in various ways but here we are using it as an **adverb** rather than as a **noun** as it seems you are thinking.

Now the adverb *there* has several senses that might require distinct cases or prepositions in other languages (or even in English if we were dealing with a noun and not *there*):

- "in" or "at" a place
- "to" or "into" a place

So you see that a sense of "there" already covers the preposition "to" thus making it redundant and in this case ungrammatical.

I have noticed that "to there" is a very common mistake among Japanese learners of English by the way.

**UPDATE**

†As Boob points out in another answer there are some circumstances under which "to there" is grammatical but I'll leave this as a footnote since this appears to be an English-learner question and I might make things more unclear if I attempt to cover those also.

Comment: lol nice catch! Actually I'm an English learner of Japanese, and am listening to Japanese music even as I write this. I've been studying Japanese for years, and I guess their grammatical tendencies are starting to have an effect on my English. lol!

Comment: Second one is also correct.

Comment: Sorry Boob you are correct. I added a footnote to my question.

Comment: So how was Japan?

Comment: Basically, "No your first example is grammatically correct and your second is incorrect" should be deleted. Prepositional deletion is common with say "If I can't make it to there by Friday, it will have to be next week" – but not mandatory. 'There' is defined as a pronoun as well as an adverb // locative/directional particle. 'From there' and 'near there' are commonplace.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Well we shall have to agree to disagree. Our idiolects must be very different in this respect. No native speaker I know *ever* says "If I can't make it to there". There is no prepositional deletion because in this construction "there" is not a noun but an adverb. "There" is not *defined* as being simultaneously every part of speech listed in a dictionary in every possibly syntactical construct. In each construct it will be *analysed* as one or another of those POS. "From there" and "near there" are commonplace because in thos constructions "there" is nominal.

Comment: You're choosing your examples. What about ''They'll have to turn back. I'm surprised they even made it to there.''?  There are well over 300 000 Google hits for "made it to there" (admittedly with a fair proportion of errors and other false positives). For some reason, there are 550 000+ for "made it to there" + surprised, with some better examples. I see you offer no evidence other than personal evaluation to back up your 'your second is incorrect' claim. ELU prefers supported answers.

Comment: "I'm surprised they even made it to there." is an example where it could occur in a native speaker's English as well as a non-native. Though " I'm surprised they even made it that far" sounds more natural. For English learners though learning that "here" and "there" don't take certain prepositions a noun would most of the time is the best advice because the times when a native speaker do otherwise are subtle to understand and can be worded more naturally anyway.

Comment: ELU is not a site aimed at English learners. They have many others.

Comment: I recommend you ask about this on some sites frequented by linguists. [linguistics.SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com) and [Quora](http://www.quora.com) both can get better answers on topics like this than I have managed.

Answer (score 1):

Without a preposition *make it* cannot be used to directly refer to a place.

- *I can't make it your birthday.
- *I can't make it France.

However, it can be used to indirectly refer to a place, using a locational pronoun:

- I can't make it there.
- Can you make it here by Thursday?

It can also refer to a time by eliding the preposition *on*:

- I can't make it (on) Thursday

With a preposition *make it* cannot refer to locational pronouns.

- *I can't make it to there.
- *Can you make it to here.

Comment: 'With a preposition _make it_ cannot refer to locational pronouns.' Have you an authority to support this statement? There are 1 500 000 Google hits for "made it to here", and I wouldn't consider it ungrammatical.

Comment: It's not ungrammatical in that it is still intelligible, but it is not standard English,  "can you make it to here by five o'clock" sounds like Singlish or something similar.

Comment: But you're choosing your examples. Let me choose one. 'We must turn back. I'm surprised we've even made it to here [= this far].' While I agree that your example would normally be used without the 'to', 'With a preposition _make it_ cannot refer to locational pronouns' is obviously not altogether true.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ahh see now you are making a constructive point. That is a case I didn't consider. The "to" can be used emphasise the distance. I wonder what rules govern that case.

Answer (score 1):

"Make it" is synonomous with "succeed" is some contexts.

Comment: True, but that isn't the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

> The place where I can get a new one is
>   pretty far and I cant make it there
>   now.

Means I cannot go now.

> I can't make it to there but I'm
>   addicted to it.

Means I cannot continue it (a game) to the specific step even though I'm addicted to it.